# How can I overwrite the old record instead of creating a new one?

Tags: django, django-forms

- I am following  <"http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/index.html"> Django Girls to create my first web application project.
- I have created form and added the username password option.
- Now ,  I login as "user1" and input some data in form.
- Again, I login as "user1" and input some data in form.
- What's happening is instead of overwriting(which I thought would happen) it's creating new database.
- I want form to update when user login again
- One Example would be very helpful thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just scroll down the blog you are referring to....they have explained the edit form in detail [link](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/index.html#edit-form)

In brief: You have to add a new url to edit your user like:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.UserEdit),
```

and in views:

```
def UserEdit(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return redirect('detail_user', pk=user.pk)
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=user)
    return render(request, 'user_detail.html', {'form': form})
```